# CoffeeScript loop creating click function listeners creates multiple listeners but with the same parameters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I have a for loop that automatically generates markers and the respective click listeners. However, all click functions seems to have the same value of the last values in the loop.

How can i get this fixed. Sample code is here;

```
  layMarkers = ->
    $.ajax '/locations',
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'json'
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            console.log errorThrown
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            buses = data["locations"]
            for i in buses
              marker = new google.maps.Marker(position: new google.maps.LatLng(i["latitude"], i["longitude"]),
              map: map
              title: "#{i["number_plate"]}, #{i["speed"]}km/h"
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP)
              marker.setMap(map)
              marker.addListener 'click', ->
                showDirection(i["terminal_number"], i["bus_number"], i["number_plate"],i["speed"] )
                # infowindow("#{i["number_plate"]}, #{i["speed"]}km/h, Terminal: #{i["terminal_number"]}, Bus Number: #{i["bus_number"]}").open map, marker
                return
```

The values passed into the showDirection is that of the last item in array being iterated over. What could i be overlooking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Comment: Try using `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of the comprehension.

Comment: @JaredSmith: CoffeeScript has the `do` keyword specifically for this sort of thing. All the JavaScript solutions still work but `do` would be more idiomatic in CoffeeScript.